# Android App to access JSON data from IBM Bluemix IoT Watson Cloud Platform

Tags: android, json, android-studio, ibm-cloud, watson-iot

I have a simple android app that I made in Android Studio which pulls JSON weather data down from openweathermap.org and it works well.

In a separate project, I am using the IBM Bluemix IoT Cloud to monitor some physical temperature data from a sensor that is being transmitted to the cloud via my Raspberry Pi.

I would like the implement this info into my app, by pulling the JSON data from the Bluemix platform.

Does anyone have any guides or tutorials for how to enable access to the JSON data directly from the Android App?

Most of what I've read on the IBM guides, seem to incorporate using Node-Red and the other IBM services instead of a homemade app.

Comment: Some android apps are available in this GitHub repository -  https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=android&type=&language=

Answer (score 0):

If I am interpreting your question correctly, you are asking how to get your sensor data back from Bluemix to an Android app you made. There are numerous solutions you can take, but one that comes to mind is using IBM Cloudant to store your device data from your IoT Cloud. Device data is stored in daily, weekly, or monthly databases depending on your selected bucket interval. Then, you can simply use the Cloudant Android SDK to get the data you need from your database.

I am unfamiliar with your setup, but you may also consider to pulling down data directly using their [REST API](https://docs.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/swagger/v0002.html) to your Android app.

---

On a side note, you can try downloading the Cloudant/Weather starter for Android here:

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/mobile/create-project/

That will give you a working example of an Android app connecting to Cloudant or pulling down weather data from Bluemix.